# Why when I press the "crtl" on Quick Edit stop editing?

Tags: javascript, edit, quick-edit

I'm using SPO and I found this error recently when I try to copy or paste  information to a list, using the `QuickEdit mode` and press the "`Ctrl`" the edition is canceled and it happens in all the SharePoints subsites,

I think is a JavaScrip error, but I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: I have observed the same from this morning. It seems some update has gone in that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, check your tenant service health.

> SharePoint Online service is degraded    View history
>
> SP73352 - Office Web Apps - Restoring service
>
> ```
>  Restoring service - Jul 30, 2016 12:51 AM
> ```
>
> Current Status: We've identified a reported issue in which Quick Edit
>   forms are closing unexpectedly. We're deploying a fix for the problem.
>   Functionality will be restored for affected users as soon as the fix
>   reaches their environment.
>
> User Impact: Users are experiencing unexpected closures of Quick Edit
>   forms when certain keyboard shortcuts are used. As a workaround, users
>   can avoid the unexpected closure by not using shortcut keys that
>   involve pressing the control key.
>
> Scope of Impact: A few customers have reported this issue, and our
>   analysis indicates that the issue only affects users who are using
>   keyboard shortcuts that use the control key in the SharePoint Online
>   Quick Edit form.
>
> Start Time: Wednesday, July 27, 2016, at 2:17 PM UTC
>
> Preliminary Root Cause: A recent feature update for the Quick Edit
>   form has caused the form to unexpectedly close when users use specific
>   shortcut keys.
>
> Next Update by: Monday, August 1, 2016, at 8:00 PM UTC